# Can I pick a power from my multiclass with Reserve Maneuver?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, powers

Reserve Maneuver (PHB2, p191):

> Benefit: Choose an encounter attack power **from your class**. The power must be your level or lower and one that you don't already have. When you regain the use of your powers at the end of any rest, you can gain the use of the chosen power instead of regaining the use of an encounter attack power of the same level or higher.

Does the highlighted *"from your class"* include the class I multiclassed into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### When you "multiclass", you're still only your original class.

Unlike a hybrid, which counts as both of its hybrid classes for all purposes, someone who's taken a class-specific multiclass feat only counts as that class for certain prerequisites. For example, consider Baron Geoff, a Warlord who's taken Student of the Sword, a Fighter multiclass feat, and Baron Theo, a Warlord|Fighter hybrid character.

Both Geoff and Theo can take feats that have Fighter as a prerequisite, and both Geoff and Theo can select paragon paths that have Fighter as a prerequisite.

However, when Geoff and Theo reach level 7 and can then select an encounter attack power "from their class", Geoff can still only select from the Warlord encounter attack powers, while Theo can select either a Warlord or a Fighter encounter attack power.

As a GM, I'd be given to a generous reading of Reserve Maneuver "in the spirit of" multiclass counting for meeting feat prerequisites. Ultimately, though, Reserve Maneuver is not Reserve Maneuver (Fighter) that gives you a Fighter encounter attack power, prerequisite: Fighter, but is a single feat that only refers to "your class", and even though it's called "multiclass", you only have a single one of those.

By that strict reading, then, Geoff can only pick a Warlord encounter attack power with Reserve Maneuver, while Theo can pick either a Warlord or a Fighter encounter attack power.